# Unknown: Using the "Twig_Loader_Array" OCstore

Tags: php, opencart, openserver, twig

> Unknown: Using the "Twig_Loader_Array" class is deprecated since Twig
> version 2.7, use "Twig\Loader\ArrayLoader" instead. in
> C:\OpenServer\domains\OCstore\system\storage\vendor\twig\twig\lib\Twig\Loader\Array.php
> on line 7

залил содержимое папки upload в open server запустил и на экране установки всерху увидел данную ошибку, в сети ничего не не нашёл, я помню кажется давно было у меня такое но не помню как исправил, помогите кто нибудь_))

Comment: Какая версия PHP?

Comment: Версия не причём стоит 8.0

Comment: Стоит попробовать запустить на 7.x